# How can I save the custom class to mysql database using hibernate java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class FilmSession that is a database entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "film_session")
public class FilmSession {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private SessionInfo sessionInfo;
}
```

Should I parse sessionInfo to JSON? If so, how? Or should I save this field like String in db?

SessionInfo class:

```
public class SessionInfo {
    private Long film_id;
    private Long cinema_id;
    private SeatStatus[][] seatStatuses;
    private Double price;
    private Date date;
}
```

Comment: `SessionInfo` should be an entity too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "film_session")
public class FilmSession {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "session_info", referencedColumnName = "session_id")
    private SessionInfo session_info;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "session_info")
public class SessionInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long session_id;
    ....
}
```